# Is it possible to modify authored cq dialog values from sling model java class

Tags: java, aem, sling-models

I am looking to modify AEM cq dialog multifield value from sling model class for that component. I need to make multifield value null from model class. This multifield has value authored from dialog UI.

Please guide me if it is possible to modify it.

AEM version - 6.5.15.0

Comment: you need add a MRE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"I am looking to modify AEM cq dialog multifield value"* - as in to modify it programmatically or do you want to modify it through [`crxde`](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-cloud-service/content/implementing/developer-tools/crxde.html?lang=en)? btw, if you could add aem version in the question that would be nice.

Comment: I want to modify it programmatically and I am using AEM 6.5

Comment: Is this an action every time the component is updated or is this a one-time action to cleanup previously entered data?

Comment: I require to do both ways, as there are 2 different scenarios. 
For first scenario - I am supposed to rename multifield of already deployed code so after renaming I want to clear the data present in existing name of multifield like I had multifield with 'name1' now I am renaming it to 'name2' so now I want to clear the data of multifield 'name1'.

For 2nd scenario : I want to clear data of textfield(already authored) everytime as per dropdown selection.